# Why does MysqlCommand.ExecuteScalar return System.NullReferenceException

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using MySQL in a VB 2013 project. I am trying to get the number of records in a table running

```
Dim SQLstr As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lieferantenartikel WHERE LiefID=1 AND LfAIDLief=1"
Dim CheckExist As New MySqlCommand(SQLstr, New MySqlConnection(strConn))
Try
    Dim recEx As Integer = CheckExist.ExecuteScalar()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

By definition COUNT(*) is supposed to return a scalar number, i.e. 0 if no records exist or otherwise any other positive number.

But I am getting a System.NullReferenceException. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is likely a result of one of the connection or command objects being `Nothing`.  Store the connection as an object variable so you can check them all with the debugger.  Also, creating a commection does not open it.

Comment: Plutonix is right. If this doesn't help try to give us the stacktrace of ex.toString

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. This happened when a table had no entries. You can Do a workaround with "ISNULL". But maybe there is a better way.

Comment: `DBNull` is not the same thing as `Nothing`.  The OP is getting a NRE which means an object being used is invalid, `DBNull` means the data is missing.

Comment: Sorry etalon: when a table has no entries then the count is 0 which is different from DBNull, That's why using count is so sexy, because you get exact the answer you are asking, i.e. how many rows are there. It will never return DBNull.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem has gon when I used an open connection instead of the connection object ! Thank you, plutonix. I have obviously overseen in the documentation that the connection has to be open.

So the corrent code is now:

```
Dim SQLstr As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lieferantenartikel WHERE LiefID=1 AND LfAIDLief=1"
Dim cConn as New MySqlConnection(strConn)
cConn.Open()
Dim CheckExist As New MySqlCommand(SQLstr, cConn)
Try
    Dim recEx As Integer = CheckExist.ExecuteScalar()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Thank you very much for your quick help!e